# How do I restrict access to mongodb to one OS user?

Tags: mongodb

How do I restrict access to mongodb to one OS user?
ie. I have a user "system" on a linux machine. I want only user "system" to access mongodb. If "tom" on linux tries to use mongo shell and connect to the localhost mongodb, it needs to fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First [enable authentication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/) for your database.

Next, create a [database admin](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/add-user-administrator/) who can create users and assign roles/privileges.

Next, create the user "system" and assign him the necessary roles for your database.

Finally, close the localhost authentication (admin) bypass once the above steps are complete:

> mongod --setParameter enableLocalhostAuthBypass=0

All of these steps are described in great detail in [Mongo's access control tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/security-access-control/).